# Blazor Server App $(document).ready() equivalent

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, document-ready

I have a Blazor Server app, I need to run a js function when the document is loaded - when I use "Static" mode, jQuery `$(document).ready()` works fine but I need to use "ServerPrerendered" mode - when user click different link on the navbar, the $(document).ready() never fires because Blazor is using SingalR to update the content. The suggested way to do that is to use `JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("jsfunctiont")` inside
`OnAfterRenderAsync` of `defaultLayout.razor` but the problem is this event happens before all sub-components are fully rendered so my js function will fail.
My question is what is the way to invoke js function after all sub-components are fully rendered? which is equivalent to `$(document).ready()` in Blazor server app using "ServerPreRendered" mode?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 8):

`OnAfterRender` (with firstRender == true) is what you need. It will not trigger until after the whole content has been rendered in the browser.

However, after your page is created the contents will change so new components will be created and existing ones destroyed. If your `jsfunction` needs to hook into every component on the page regardless of when it is created then your approach won't work. You'd need the individual components to also override `OnAfterRenderAsync` and call `jsfunction` passing a reference to themself.

Comment: The js function needs to be run when all subcomponents get rendered the OnAfterRender with firstRender on DefaultLayout.razor happens before all child components ... the js function is trying to look into whole DOM to do something

Answer (score 2):

Had the same challenge with `$(document).ready()` not triggering when new components were added/removed over SignalR (using Blazor server side).

Instead of hooking into every component's `OnAfterRenderAsync` and calling `JsRuntime.Invoke..` I solved it by using
`$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () { // doyourwork });`

Answer (score 2):

I needed this so I could collapse my Bootstrap5 menu after clicking on a link in a mobile screen. My solution was to place this in my _Layout.chtml file, it will only execute if the Navbar is actually collapsed, note I gave my NavBar toggle button an id "navbarToggler":

```
    // Make Bootsrap NavBar collapse after clicking on a link.
    $(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () { 
        if ($('#navbarToggler').hasClass('collapsed'))
        {
            $('.nav-link').on("click", function() {
                $('button.navbar-toggler').click();
            });
        }
    });
```